# Can I manually adjust a particular window's transparency using Metacity composite mode?

Tags: 10.10, xorg, metacity, compositing

Compiz doesn't work correctly with my graphics card (Intel 82852/855GM), so I use Metacity composite mode, which works fine. Sometimes I'd like to make a particular window of my choice semi-transparent (setting up a transparency ratio for all active windows and another for all inactive ones is not enough). Is there a way to control transparency of a particular window with Metacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install transset
```

You then use `transset` to interactively make windows transparent. I can't find any help for it though but I assume there's an option of scripting it to almost-automatically beat down windows you want transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I've [found the answer](http://stillstup.blogspot.com/2008/10/transparency-in-gnomemetacity.html), it is "transset" (sudo apt-get install transset, transset and click on the window to make transparent).